# Show keypad in Android below the text field

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, rhomobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android soft keyboard covers edittext field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

My Rhomobile application successfully running in Android Samsung Tablet emulator. I am having issue in showing keypad in Rhomobile application when the form has more than 2 input fields. The keypad hides the text field entirely in device. How can i move up the text field from key pad so that it will be visible for all fields.

Comment: [Related SO-question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

Answer (score 0):

are you using `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in your manifest?

Comment: Yes. but having same issue. Any other idea?