# Cant see edit texts that are in a scroll view while typing

Tags: android, scrollview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

The soft keyboard covers up my `EditText` fields when attempting to type into the `EditText`.

How can i prevent the soft keyboard from covering up my `EditText` fields?

After pressing the back button i can see what i typed, because the soft keyboard is no longer covering the `EditText`.

I am using the galaxy 10.1 inch tablet.

**XML**

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="400dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1) Project"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/projectET"
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Project" 
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/projectCBM"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="55dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2) Customer"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/customerET"
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:hint="Customer" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/customerCBM"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="55dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/material1"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="3) Material"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/materialET"
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:inputType="textCapWords"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Material" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/materialCBM"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="55dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="4) Phase"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/fazeET"
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="Phase" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/fazeCBM"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:enabled="false" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="5)"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:enabled="false" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="6)"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:enabled="false" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="7)"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:enabled="false" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="8)"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="9)"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="10)"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android soft keyboard covers edittext field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

Comment: I added the exact attribute you need to add to your `Activity` for this to work. Please view the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft). This will allow your UI to resize when the keyboard comes up. Allowing the user to see the `EditText` while typing in the keyboard.

Add this attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml to your `Activity`.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3295913/427763)

Comment: what if wanted to specific behaviour on difference fragment child of fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have some fixed layout above your `ScrollView`, because usually the `ScrollView` would automatically scroll to the Focused component.

So, if I am right, there is two options (that I know):

1. Bring the `ScrollView` over the keyboard or
2. Verify layout changes to dynamically bring `ScrollView` to an upper
   and visible position, after `ScrollView` is visible it will
   automatically show the right `EditText` to the user.

Comment: Do you think you could farther explain to me how I would go about doing the second option?

Comment: You will need to override the main view from your layout and on method onMeasure() you will receive calls when your layout is resized, than you can callback your activity to reposition your view, but dont forget to undo it latter..... In my case I did it whenever I had a too small view, so in devices with smaller screen I remove all uneeded componnets.