# How to change position of LinearLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am not able to see editText control when I typing in because soft keyboard covers up(hide) editText control code sample is as below :

```
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams LY_Scroll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 388);
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams LY_BOTTOM = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 45);
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams LY_EDIT = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            267, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams LY_BTN = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams LY_TEXT = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout_all = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout_all.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout_all.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);

        // top
        setContentView(layout_all);

        sv = new ScrollView(this);
        sv.setLayoutParams(LY_Scroll);

        text_Show = new TextView(this);
        text_Show.setLayoutParams(LY_TEXT);
        sv.addView(text_Show);

        // bottom
        LinearLayout layout_bottom = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout_bottom.setLayoutParams(LY_BOTTOM);
        layout_bottom.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setLayoutParams(LY_EDIT);

        sendBtn = new Button(this);
        sendBtn.setLayoutParams(LY_BTN);
        sendBtn.setText("Send");

        layout_bottom.addView(editText);
        layout_bottom.addView(sendBtn);

        layout_all.addView(sv);
        layout_all.addView(layout_bottom);

        ........
    }
```

Can any one have idea how to make editText visible when I type in soft keyboard ?

Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the best way is to use [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) to control how your dialog should work. Perhaps you want the `adjustPan` option, although the docs recommend not using it. See [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3295913/1270789).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest under the activity where you have EditText.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```