# Android application keyboard overlap screen instead of pushing application up in 4.1

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing android application using cordova 2.4

Problem is keyboard overlap screen instead pushing application up.

My text field hide behind phone keypad.

Please share if any one know solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check into adding this to your activity xml:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

There are some good tutorials out there like this one: http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/

This particular questions has been asked many times as well, see here: [Android soft keyboard covers edittext field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this on my manifest file but nothing change

Comment: still an issue in 2019 - and for users on phonegap build - can't edit manifest.