# scroll edit text along with soft keyboard android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-scrollview

> Hi,I have registraion page & i m using in that scroll view but when page display with softKeyboard bottom all fields hide I want scroll that field also when keyboard appear. I used 'adjustPan' or multiple combination in manifest.xml but it is not work.Please help me how can i scroll with keyboard.Here is my code

manifest.xml

```
<activity android:label="Registration" android:name="Registration"  
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

My layout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
      <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10px" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:text="Registration Form"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
         </TableRow>

              <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/firstName1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/firstName"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/middleName1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:text=" Middle Name :"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/middleName"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
        </TableRow>

           <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastName1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastName"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" >


            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:text=" ITS Id(Optional) :"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/itsId"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="8" />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="text" 
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

        </TableRow>


        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/password1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLength="8"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </TableRow>


        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/confirmPassword1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/confirmPassword"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLength="8"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </TableRow>


        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:text=" Email :"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLength="200"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:text=" Gender :"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:entries="@array/gender_array" />

        </TableRow>
       <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >


            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Keep Private" />



        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="addNewProfile"
                android:text="Submit" />


             <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="cancelActivity"
                android:text="Cancel" />

          </TableRow>
         </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

You may also follow the this link for more information [Android soft keyboard covers edittext field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)