# Soft keyboard hides half of EditText

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a `ListView` and the last list item contains `EditText`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/test" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendImageButton"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/messageEditText"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:minHeight="55dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/messageEditText"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="55dp"
            android:maxWidth="55dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/sendmessage" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Half of the `EditText` is hidden. I also can't scroll `ListView`. Any solution?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android soft keyboard covers edittext field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue event after setting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" and using a scrollview. Any other suggestions?

Comment: [The property android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" doesn't work with full screen activity, you have to remove activity full screen flags in order to get advantage of adjust resize. ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42204350/3926264)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Solution was to set an `android:softInputMode` attribute to `adjustResize` in Manifest and put layout(not list item layout) inside a ScrollView.

Answer (score 9):

I Had a similar issue, then i used `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field).. It works very well for me..

Comment: Hi @IgorGanapolsky.. stateHidden setting will hide soft keyboard when user enters new Activity (even if EditText control gains the focus). Soft keyboard will be shown only when user clicks the edit box control.

Answer (score 3):

From my early days as a Android Developer I struggled with the virtual keyboard. I am amazed that Android is still not giving an elegant and clear solution for this.

So here is the Workaround that will put this mess behind you. it will work without the ScrollView workaround or giving away your full screen flag.

1. Add this awesome Library to your gradle file:

compile'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:1.0.1'

2. Make sure your activity has the following keyboard settings:

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

3. wrap your EditText with a vertical LinearLayout and add a View with Visibility of Gone:

   ```
   <com.ylimitapp.ylimitadmin.views.NormalFontEditText
       android:id="@+id/input_et"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
       android:imeOptions="actionSend"
       android:paddingStart="20dp"
       android:paddingEnd="40dp"
       android:paddingTop="10dp"
       android:maxHeight="120dp"
       android:adjustViewBounds= "true"
       android:scrollHorizontally="false"
       android:textColorHint="#7b7b7b"
       android:hint="@string/type_your_message"
       android:background="@drawable/msg_inputfield_bg"
       android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
       android:textSize="15.33sp"
       />

       <View
           android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="20dp"
           android:visibility="gone"
           />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. calculate the screen size so you can calculate the height of the view that pushes the EditText:

   ```
   private void storeScreenHeightForKeyboardHeightCalculations() {
               Rect r = new Rect();
               View rootview = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView(); 
               rootview.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
               mOriginalScreenHeight = r.height();

               Rect rectangle = new Rect();
               Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
               window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
               int statusBarHeight = rectangle.top;
               int contentViewTop =
                       window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
               int titleBarHeight= contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;

               if (titleBarHeight == 0) {
                   mOriginalScreenHeight -= (24 * Utils.getDensity(getContext()));
               }
           }
   ```

   5. Add a Listener for keyboard open and close event and then set the height of the View below the EditText on runtime so we will set the height properly on any device and custom keyboards. then simply make it Visible when the Keyboard is Open:

> ```
> private void addkeyBoardlistener() {
>            KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(
>                             getActivity(),
>                             new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
>                                 @Override
>                                 public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
>                                     if (isOpen) {
>                                         Rect r = new Rect();
>                                         View rootview = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView(); // this = activity
>                                         rootview.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
>                                         int keyboardHeight = (mOriginalScreenHeight - r.height());
>                                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) keyboard_view.getLayoutParams();
>                                         params.height = (int) ((keyboardHeight + 5 * Utils.getDensity(getContext())));
>                                         keyboard_view.setLayoutParams(params);
>                                         keyboard_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>                                     } else {
>                                         keyboard_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>                                     }
>                                 }
>                             });
>                 }
> ```

This is the result:

[image: Result:]

Answer (score 2):

### Disable the keyboard on window startup

```
this .getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams. SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN );
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an `android:softInputMode` attribute for your Activity element in your Manifest.

See the [Manifest  documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for a full list of valid values and their effect. The ones of particular interest to you will likely be `adjustPan` and `adjustResize`.

Comment: @Tanis.7x  You cannot use both - `adjustPan` and `adjustResize`.

Comment: I never said to use both- I mentioned both because either could be applicable depending on the desired end behavior. You should look at the documentation for both and choose the one that provides the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the manifest like so:

```
<activity
    android:name="your_activity_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
```

Then add `paddingBottom="20dp"` in your layout and editText.