# Soft keyboard hides EditText

Tags: java, android

Already tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the manifest file,
When I tap the bottom (4th one from top) EditText, the soft keyboard partially hides it:

[image]

This however does not happen in the Android emulator - the screen pans and I get the focus on the EditText (keyboard still covers a small part of the EditText but it's acceptable I think):

[image]

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128193/soft-keyboard-hides-half-of-edittext

Answer (score 1):

Put your **EditText** inside the **ScrollView** and then give property **adjustResize**, instead of **adjustPan**, it will automatically adjust your screen and its components.

Comment: I want everything to remain in it's place. Won't 'adjustResize' move things around when the keyboard pops up? I don't mind it will move the whole thing as a 'block', though.