# Keyboard overlapping issue on EditText with adjustpan not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using this code But the keyboard is still overlapping EditText. what can be done

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/optionsBar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:animationCache="false"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:listSelector="#00000000"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:scrollingCache="false"
                 />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:background="@drawable/top_bar_bg"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="43dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Your Message"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:id="@+id/chatBox"
                android:background="@drawable/message_type_area"
                 />

            <Button 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_width="37dp"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:background="@drawable/send_btn"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/sendBtn"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

 <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
```

[image]

Comment: did you try adding bottom margin/padding on your edittext?

Comment: its single line text with gravity at center.

Comment: Try using `adjustResize` instead

Comment: i have tried almost all nothing is working

Comment: do you, by any chance, have transparent status bar, navigation bar or full screen activity?

Comment: yes, full screen activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adjustResize` fails to work when you use a FullScreenActivity. One solution would be to contain the whole layout in a ScrollView and scroll it to position `editText.getY() + editText.getMeasuredHeight()` when the editText gains focus.

Or, if you want a quick fix to the problem, have at look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494006/1393623) on a similar question here.

Answer (score 1):

Full screen disables soft input adjustment modes. See:

[Android How to adjust layout in Full Screen Mode when softkeyboard is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4404

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/T193nVgXDSA/O6UZmDqskFYJ

Answer (score 0):

The property android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" doesn't work with full screen activity, you have to remove activity full screen flags in order to get advantage of adjust resize.

[see this: A fullscreen window will ignore a value of SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE for the window's softInputMode field; the window will stay fullscreen and will not resize.](http://%200%20down%20vote%20%09%20%20The%20property%20android:windowSoftInputMode=%22adjustResize%22%20doesn't%20work%20with%20full%20screen%20activity,%20you%20have%20to%20remove%20activity%20full%20screen%20flags%20in%20order%20to%20get%20advantage%20of%20adjust%20resize.%20see%20this:%20A%20fullscreen%20window%20will%20ignore%20a%20value%20of%20SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE%20for%20the%20window's%20softInputMode%20field;%20the%20window%20will%20stay%20fullscreen%20and%20will%20not%20resize.)

Answer (score 0):

android:maxLines="1" in your xml file and use in mainfiest file.

```
        <activity
        android:name="Logintab"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```