# Android soft keyboard covers Edittext android

Tags: android

Android: show soft keyboard automatically covers half of Edittext field after clicking on that particular Edittext implemented in the bottom of the layout. When request focus on EditText soft keyboard opens and it will shift the layout upward but covers up the half of Edittext field.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.12"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_back"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_nav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_back"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleView"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/list_circle"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_circle"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo8" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="\@gaurav.yadav"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView81"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1d" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"></LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_p"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_post"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.87"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_topcollege"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.12"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_attachment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView28"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:hint="Write a Answer...."
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView27"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put your code inside of scrollview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128193/soft-keyboard-hides-half-of-edittext

Comment: #Pankaj Ji follow @BhaveshRangani's Comment

Comment: Dear, Bhavesh I put my code inside scrollview but it cannot work for me.

Answer (score 1):

set flag in the manifest as,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11713161)

Comment: It would be great that you have improved my answer with your knowledge then adding such comments, because such comments will not gonna help the user to resolved issue, anyways i do take care of asking users about more info and logs in comments.

Comment: this is a comment rather than an answer. An answer requires a better explanation, as to why for example would you need to set the SoftInputMode as hidden in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Put your required code in scrollview, than for activity class you have to set one property

```
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

set focus to dummy layout or any view in your xml 
like

```
           <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
```