# How to solve bottom edittext half hide in android?

Tags: android-edittext, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard, adjustpan

I am tried this solution but I didn't work in my current scenario,

- [Soft keyboard hides half of EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128193/soft-keyboard-hides-half-of-edittext)
- In Current code I set in Manifest

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

- When I click and focus on edittext on bottom It's Half Edittext shown.

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOzPM.png