# Android soft keyboard hides button

Tags: android, keyboard, scrollview

I do have a simple login view like shown below.

If any `EditText` gains focus, the keyboard will be shown (soft). The red dashed line should outline this behavior:

[image: Keyboard]

What I need is, that the Buttons at the bottom (Signup & Help) are **invisible** while Keyboard is showing. The bottom end of the login button should be over the keyboard, so that both `EditTexts`  **and** the `Login Button` are visible.

At best half of the Logo should be visible if possible (depending on screen size)

It would be perfectly fine to define an extra layout xml like "keyboard is visible" if that's possible.

Comment: did you check adjustPan or adjustResize in manifest

Comment: Yes I did, but then the login button gets cutoff a little

Comment: <activity 
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: I am in the same boat as you and it has been bugging me for days. Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android soft keyboard covers edittext field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

Answer (score 7):

1) `ScrollView` as parent layout so that it can be scrolled by user.

2) using only `adjustResize`

3) Use 
[software keyboard show/hide event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android?lq=1)   to have more control. You can set visibility of the layout below login button with  View.GONE while keyboard is visibe.

extra:

Check [Specifying the Input Method Type](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html) . Next and Done actions for  convenience of user

Comment: I dont get the point of using a custom keyboard layout. Why do I need this? I just want to set some views invisible if keyboard is shown and  change the scrollviews content offset a little. Isn't there any other way? Can't believe that it is that hard. In iOS it's like 5 lines of code to achieve this behavior...

Comment: @Alexander so first add adjustResize atribute. Then inside code   keyboard appear with OnTouch (set all editText listens to same OnTouch) and inside OnTouch set visibility of some views that you do not want to  show. On back button press (which we assume will hide keyboard) set visibility to visible to show views again. (Note: test by yourself if it is correctly handle all keyboard  disappearance.)

Comment: @Alexander check .I think you can use these solutions

Answer (score 3):

Do somthing like dis. Here "android:name"  is your activity.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.tryitonjewelry.EnterStoreRegisterNew"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_enter_store_register_new"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ENTERSTOREREGISTERNEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: adjustPan as well as adjustResize will not work because the login button gets cutoff a little

Comment: try adjustResize|adjustPan

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it by few steps. When `KeyBoard` popup then do the following steps or you can wrap these in a method...

1. Get the window height.
2. Determine the keyboard height.
3. Scroll your view above the keyboard height using `scrollTo()` method.

Comment: "When the KeyBoard popup" is a little to less information. Is there a keyboard listener or any System Notification like in iOS? Further I read that there is no method to determine the height of the keyboard