# Android. Views hide by keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, hide, orientation

I have vertical linear layout with multiline edit text and 2 buttons below. When I try to write something the keyboard hide these views. I tried to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but its not help. Edit text rise above the keyboard but buttons are still not visible. Help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: try this : android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android soft keyboard hides button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906912/android-soft-keyboard-hides-button)

Answer (score 0):

Put your LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. That way you can scroll to the other views after the EditText fields gain focus.

Comment: very bad solution, its forbide me to scroll edit text. To do this i need to write additional code.

Answer (score 0):

When you go for edit text, the keyboard shows up for input and hides the button or other widget when you are editing.
It should dismiss when you are done with edittext.
This should work.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activityname"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" >
```

Comment: already tried this. Doesn't work. Its rise edit text but buttons still under the keyboard.

Comment: Am not clear with your question. Do you want to dismiss the keyboard after edit text ? or do you want to show the button even when editing text ?

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same issue. Resolved it with 2 simple steps.

1. Put your view inside scroll

   ```
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ```

   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   ```
   <LinearLayout   your code
   ```
2. Edit manifest for softinputmode.

Comment: very bad idea to put scrollable views ( edit text) to scroll view