# Push layout further when soft keyboard opens

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a `RelativeLayout` with an `EditText` and a `Button` in it.

When the keyboard opens, the layout is pushed up to show the `EditText` above the keyboard, but it's not enough to bring up the `Button` to prevent it from hiding under the keyboard.

Is it possible to move the layout up more, or somehow prevent it from being under the keyboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has been answered here: [Android soft keyboard covers edittext field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3295672/475217)

Ideally you will be able to use `windowSoftInputMode` to control how your Activity is moved around when the soft keyboard is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The behavior itself is right. The amount of scroll needs to be somehow increased.

Comment: Could you add some buffer below your Button that would force the layout to move up even higher? Perhaps a transparent View set to a certain height?

Comment: There was a famous android bug in the app. When the app is in immersive full screen mode, the keyboard pushing is messed up. If you disable the full screen, everything works fine..

Comment: @MiroMarkaravanes are you aware of a fix for that or a way around for the apps being in full screen? Thanks!

Comment: @commandantp I haven't found any solution for that yet. But I suppose Google might have patched that for KitKat or Lollipop.