# EditText is hidden on focus

Tags: android, user-interface

Edittext is hidden on keyboard focus. Once the i click the edittext, keyboard hides it!! Have added "adjustResize" in my manifest, still no success.

This is my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="dev.sixhops.app.activities.ChatActivity"
android:background="#FFF3E0"
>

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar"></include>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/chatList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:background="#FFF3E0"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FFF3E0">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send_now"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_orange"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/message_send"
        android:minEms="15"
        android:hint="message here!!"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size3"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bg_white"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:singleLine="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there anything that i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activity `onCreate()` method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

it will adjust your window above the keyboard when its open.

Comment: can you please provide some screenshot about your problem?

Comment: Sorry i do not have the reputation to add an image!! Basically its a chat screen like whats app where-in the edittext is at the bottom. It is very similar to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262414/android-keyboard-hides-edittext

Comment: Can you please double check your layout background and other children views' backgrounds as well? This might happen !

Answer (score 0):

Had to resize my view based on keyboard shown/hidden!!

```
class KeyboardUtil {
    private View decorView;
    private View contentView;
    private float initialDpDiff = -1;

    public KeyboardUtil(Activity act, View contentView) {
        this.decorView = act.getWindow().getDecorView();
        this.contentView = contentView;
        decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
    }

    //a small helper to allow showing the editText focus
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener onGlobalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
            decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

            //get the height diff as dp
            float heightDiffDp = convertPixelsToDp(decorView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top), decorView.getContext());

            //set the initialDpDiff at the beginning. (on my phone this was 73dp)
            if (initialDpDiff == -1) {
                initialDpDiff = heightDiffDp;
            }

            //if it could be a keyboard add the padding to the view
            if (heightDiffDp - initialDpDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...

                contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, (int) convertDpToPixel((heightDiffDp - initialDpDiff), decorView.getContext()));
                if (mChatAdapter.getItemCount() > 0)
                    mRecyclerChat.smoothScrollToPosition(mChatAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
            } else {
                contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                if (mChatAdapter.getItemCount() > 0)
                    mRecyclerChat.smoothScrollToPosition(mChatAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
            }
        }
    };
```