# how do I make my edit texts appear above the keyboad

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, keyboard

there have been similar questions like this but none of them worked for me, so here my register layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/signin_page_background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="45dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/retour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:onClick="goback"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_ios_24"
                android:tint="#191919" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Retour"
                android:textColor="#191919"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <com.github.captain_miao.optroundcardview.OptRoundCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:optRoundCardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:optRoundCardElevation="0dp"
        app:optRoundCardLeftBottomCorner="false"
        app:optRoundCardLeftTopCorner="true"
        app:optRoundCardRightBottomCorner="false"
        app:optRoundCardRightTopCorner="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        >
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:keyboardNavigationCluster="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/inscrivez"
                    android:textColor="#191919"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/username_signup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/user_icon"
                    android:drawableTint="#696969"
                    android:hint="@string/username"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#191919"
                    android:textColorHint="#696969"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:background="#696969" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_signup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/email_icon"
                    android:drawableTint="#696969"
                    android:hint="E-mail"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#191919"
                    android:textColorHint="#696969"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:background="#696969" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/pw_signup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/pasword_icon"
                    android:drawableTint="#696969"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#191919"
                    android:textColorHint="#696969"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:background="#696969" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_signin"
                    android:text="@string/insc_btn"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>


        </ScrollView>

    </com.github.captain_miao.optroundcardview.OptRoundCardView>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

whenever the screan is small, and when the user types the passwor and the keyboard hides the editText.
if anyone can correct my xml to make the editText appear above the keybord whenever the user is typing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262414/android-keyboard-hides-edittext

Comment: already checked this but none works for me

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView as Root layout.