# windowSoftInputMode not working inside scrollView android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

My keyboard is hiding EditTexts. I have tried adjustPan, adjustResize, changing ScrollView size... and other things from questions like this [Android Keyboard hides EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262414/android-keyboard-hides-edittext), but I think is something related with ScrollView inside ConstraintLayout.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="feature_my_zone.presentation.profile.addresses.editadd.EditAddAddressFragment">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_layout_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        style="@style/text_medium_white_17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_16"
        android:text="@string/btn_add"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayoutBack">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_16">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                style="@style/text_medium_white_34"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_16"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblName"
                style="@style/text_regular_white_17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_24"
                android:text="@string/lbl_name"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                style="@style/text_regular_gray_ghost_15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblZip"
                style="@style/text_regular_white_17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_24"
                android:text="@string/lbl_zip"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tvZip"
                style="@style/text_regular_gray_ghost_15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblZip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblLocation"
                style="@style/text_regular_white_17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_24"
                android:text="@string/lbl_location"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvZip" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
                style="@style/text_regular_gray_ghost_15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblLocation" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblProvince"
                style="@style/text_regular_white_17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_24"
                android:text="@string/lbl_province"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvLocation" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tvProvince"
                style="@style/text_regular_gray_ghost_15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblProvince" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblAddress"
                style="@style/text_regular_white_17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_24"
                android:text="@string/lbl_address"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvProvince" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
                style="@style/text_regular_gray_ghost_15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblAddress" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The layout is showing well

[image]

I know there is a lot of questions about this, but still couldn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Define id appBarLayoutBack to include tag like:

```
  <include
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayoutBack"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_layout_back" />
```

Or whichever you want to set this.
You set toptobottom id 'appBarLayoutBack' this one. which doesn't exist in your layout thats the reason it is not showing scrollview data.

Comment: this is not the problem, the ID is inside this layout and the scrollview data is showing well, I'll add a picture