# ScrollView is not showing Editext after cliking on it and KeyBoard pops up

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have a problem and I don't find how to fix it.

I have an editText in my view, which is in a scrollView. When I click on it, keyboard shows up, and then I have to scroll to show my editext on my screen.

EDIT: My editText isn't hidden behind my keyboard, because my scrollview is adapted to my view when keyboard shows up. I've set

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in my manifest

I show you with screens of my App.

Thank you very much

[image: Here's my view before I click on my editText]

[image: Here's my view after I've clicked on my editText, My editext is hidden]

[image: Then I have to scroll to see my EdiText]

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262414/android-keyboard-hides-edittext

Comment: In my case, keyboard isn't hidding the editText, because my view is adjusted to the new size of screen: as you can se I can scroll to show my EditText