# How to make Keyboard appear below the EditText ONLY

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to make the keyboard appear only below the `EditText`, using `AdjustPan`, I'm getting this :

[image]

I tried to hide the suggestions part of the keyboard, but it didn't help, a part of the `EditText` is still hidden under the keyboard.

I'm using the code below :

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan</item>
</style>
```

EditText :

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_query"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_bg"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLength="250"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
```

I just want the keyboard to be exactly below the `EditText`.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262414/android-keyboard-hides-edittext

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
```

and when you want to create your dialog

```
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle)
```