# Edit text is hide when custom keyboard is displayed

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I am using custom keyboard using KeyboardView. It is working fine. But if I place the edit text in the bottom of the screen, my custom keyboard is hide that edit text. But if I use native keyboard edit text is automatically come to top of that edit text. How to do this for my custom keyboard? can we give `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for this custom keyboard?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Keyboard hides EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262414/android-keyboard-hides-edittext)

Comment: This is for Android native keyboard. For Custom keyboard it is not working.