# Keyboard is not scrolling EditText above

Tags: java, android

I am using this code. However when ever i click on EditText to open the keyboard, the view is not totally up. Why the view is not going up all the way, EditText is hidden behind Keyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg" 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >

       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bar_bg"
     >

        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            >

                 <ImageView 
                     android:id="@+id/loadingAnimationImg"
                     android:layout_height="35dp"
                     android:layout_width="35dp"
                     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                     android:contentDescription="@null"
                     android:background="@drawable/img05"/>

                 <ImageView 
                     android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="120dp"
                     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                     android:contentDescription="@null"
                     android:src="@drawable/simple_logo"/>

         </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:numColumns="5"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/hashtagText"
        />


    <com.trib.devicebee.custom.FlowLayout 
        android:id="@+id/flowLayout"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/hashTagsText"
        android:hint=""
        android:inputType="textFilter" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goAheadBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/go_ahead_btn"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to play with **android:windowSoftInputMode** attribute in AndroidManifest.xml - **"adjustPan"** could be the answer.

```
<activity
    android:name="MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I came up with is to put everything in **scrollView**.

- Now in manifest

  ```
  <activity
      android:name="MyActivity"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
  </activity>
  ```
- Now use the onfocusChangeListener on the editText you want to focus

  ```
  editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
          if (b){
          scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,editText.getBottom()+5);
          }
      }
  });
  ```

And we are done.

Comment: Please do not [copy and paste answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field/39357566#39357566) between questions. If the same answer applies to both questions, one question should be flagged as a duplicate, not answered.

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"