# Resize layout when appears custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, resize, custom-keyboard

I implemented a custom keyboard in my app according this tutorial (http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) and I'm having some layout problems with the keyboard. When I use the soft keyboard the content layout scrolls up and appears the keyboard, but when I use my custom keyboard the content layout don't change and the keyboard layout appears over the content layout. How to resolve this? I want the content layout scrolls up.

See the image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OJBW.jpg)

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571712/keyboard-is-not-scrolling-edittext-above/27571879#27571879

Comment: Did you find solution? Tron's solution not working

Comment: @streamride  did you find any solution?