# Why the android keyboard cover my EditText?

Tags: android

I define EditText on the button of my application
Its look like this:

[image]

But when i focus on the EditText of the Notes the keyboard  is open and cover all my EditText and i can't see what i typing in the EditText.

When i hide the keyboard i see the right text that i typed in.

The xml of the LinearLayout of the EditText:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Notes:"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:focusable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to use windowSoftInputMode attribute in your activity  in the manifest. Somelike this:

```
<activity name="YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    ...
</activity>
```

Check those links:
[Android soft keyboard covers edittext field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Answer (score 1):

The only solution to this is to put your text box in a different place.

Think about it...  Do you really want your text box ABOVE your keyboard?

This is a fairly common issue, and it something that should always be taken into account when designing your layout.

Comment: no .. but the UI design is what i did.

Comment: there must be other solution - i so this in some other application.

Answer (score 0):

so this solve my problem ( thanks to @Coeus )

I define on the manifest this line

```
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```