# Keyboard hides view above Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview, keyboard, android-recyclerview

I want is the following sort of layout:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
  <ToolBar></ToolBar>
  <RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>
  <RecyclerView></RecyclerView>
  <LinearLayout>
    <EditText></EditText>
  </LinearLayout>
<CoordinatorLayout>
```

However, my issue is when I click on my `EditText`, the keyboard pops up and shows the `RecyclerView` perfectly, but when I try to scroll further up, I can't seem to see my `RelativeLayout`, nor can I see my `ToolBar`. However, when I don't have the keyboard up, I can see everything fine. Here are some images showing what's happening:
[image: This is my image before I click on the keyboard]

[image: This is my image after I click the keyboard]

I understand it is most likely because I don't have a parent `ScrollView` that nests the entire layout, but I can't seem to have that because of my `RecyclerView`. Is there either a. a way to implement a sort of custom RecyclerView so I can have a `ScrollView` parent layout or b. find some way for me to be able to scroll and see my `ToolBar` and `RelativeLayout` in addition to my `RecyclerView`? I've included my attempt with a `ScrollView` but I still can only see the `RecyclerView` when I click on the `EditText`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Code:
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity android:name=".com.tabs.activity.Comments"
        android:label="View Post"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".com.tabs.activity.news_feed"/>
    </activity>
```

comments.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:flatui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/comments_coordinator_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/layout_comments">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/view_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:background="#e6e6e6">

                <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                    fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                    fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/poster_name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:id="@+id/post_date"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_below="@id/poster_name"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/view_status" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/send_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <com.cengalabs.flatui.views.FlatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom|left"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:hint="Comment back!"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    flatui:fl_fieldStyle="fl_box"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                <com.cengalabs.flatui.views.FlatButton
                    android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="send"
                    flatui:theme="@array/sea"
                    flatui:fl_textAppearance="fl_light"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view_post"
                android:layout_above="@id/send_message"
                android:id="@+id/view_comments">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: use only `stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I did as you suggested and it did not fix my problem. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field

Comment: the same solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up

Comment: Those actually do not answer my question. 2nd question answers how you can hide a view which is using adjustNothing and 1st question asks why the EditText is not showing.  My question is why my View is being pushed up and not being shown when I click on the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

According to:

> I understand it is most likely because I don't have a parent
>   `ScrollView` that nests the entire layout, but I can't seem to have
>   that because of my `RecyclerView`. Is there either a. a way to
>   implement a sort of custom RecyclerView so I can have a `ScrollView`
>   parent layout or b. find some way for me to be able to scroll and see
>   my `ToolBar` and `RelativeLayout` in addition to my `RecyclerView`?
>   I've included my attempt with a `ScrollView` but I still can only see
>   the `RecyclerView` when I click on the `EditText`. Any help is
>   appreciated. Thanks!

So you need to extend range of existing `ScrollView` view. Just put `AppBarLayout` and `RelativeLayout` view into new  vertical oriented 'LinearLayout', as `ScrollView` takes only one view. This new created `ViewGroup` would be an only child of 'CoordinatorLayout'.

Once you wrap `AppBarLayout` and `RelativeLayout' into new made`LinearLayout`, put it into existing`ScrollView`.

Hope you now understand how to do it. If not, tell me and I would tomorrow in the early morning edit my post and change your actual code with desired one.

Comment: Well my issue is that the `ScrollView` can not be a parent of a `RecyclerView` because then you would have a nested scroll view wouldn't you?

Comment: no, because `ScrollView` can only has only one child. The child of ScrollView would be nested ViewGroups holder.

Answer (score 0):

put your `<RecyclerView>` in the one `<LinearLayout>`
and set your `linearlayout` as `match_parent` but in your `RecyclerView` set `height="0dp"` and use `weight="1"` like this :

```
    <CoordinatorLayout>
         <ToolBar></ToolBar>
         <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

                   <RecyclerView
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="0dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"></RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>
        <EditText
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"
              app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"></EditText>
    <CoordinatorLayout>
```

and then, when your keyboard opens your recyclerview will not be under keyboard and your can scroll to see items under keybard

good lock