# Keyboard covers my textarea android

Tags: android

I have a text area like this

[image]

When i try to write in the last section, at the bottom, the keyboard covers all of this.

EDIT: This is my layout. The problem is in the linearlayout with id: layout_notas

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_crear_entrenamiento"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_ejercicios"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_info"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="Ejercicios"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ejercicios"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_notas"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_ejercicios"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="Notas"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/notas"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textArea_information"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:lines="6"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:text="Hora inicio:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvHoraInicio"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="time"
                    android:ems="3"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/etHoraInicio"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvHoraInicio"/>

                <TextView
                    android:text="Ubicacion:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvUbicacion"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:ems="7"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:id="@+id/etUbicacion"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvUbicacion"/>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: Post your layout xml

Comment: Add a scrollview as your parent. You could either let user scroll the scrollview manually or make some animation to scoll up the scrollview which cover the textview like most ios application do. But I think after you add a scrollview android will automatically scoll it to visible point

Comment: Inside Manifest in your Activity tag add   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"  and add scrollview as your parent.

Comment: i think it works for me. this is the best solution?

Comment: Same Question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3295672/6759926), Take a look