# In my layout one edit text and one button below edit text when i click on edit text then layout show above the soft input

Tags: javascript, android

In my layout one *edit text and one button below edit text when i click on edit text then layout show above t*he soft input

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! As you might understand, your current question is not of good quality as it is unclear what you're asking. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android soft keyboard covers edittext field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file under your current activity, write following code:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Your Activity in manifest will look somewhat like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name="Your.Activity.Name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: @Safal Bhatia: If you are satisfied with the answer, Please upvote and accept the answer. It will be appreciated. Thanks