# Android Jelly Bean - Keyboard hides text input in full screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

When I use the soft keyboard to type in a text inside a `WebView`, it hides the field and I cannot see what I am typing.

I found out in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) and also [this link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field), [also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible/19494006#19494006) and many other websites that by using :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in the Android Manifest would do the trick.

It normally works BUT in my case I have my `WebView` in **Full Screen** where this prevents the above `adjustResize` code to work.

I also tried in `onCreate()` the following code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

where it does it full screen but still the `adjustResize` is not working.

So my question is how I can use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` or any other way and also have my `WebView` in fullscreen as well?

EDIT:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This code works but not in Full Screen.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
WebView webView=new WebView(getActivity());
        webView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getWindow().clearFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't make it Full screen.

Comment: i've edited my answer try this if it didn't work i wish you good luck searching for sollution

Comment: Its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to get this work on an app I am working upon. I haven'y yet gotten an answer as well.

As for you, you can try setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the rootView of your layout.