# Activity fullscreen DialogFragment contain EditText not resize when keyboard show

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment

```
<style name="Full.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_FF3049</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/edit_text_cursor_blue</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

this is my activity style, and i custom a dialogFragment with edittext show in Activity

when i click edittext ,the dialogfragment not resize up ,and the keyboard keep out the fragment

how can i fix this ？
thanks！

Comment: You should provide your activity code, where you show the dialog, and a screenshot of the issue you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the Manifest node for the Activity, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786200/526635).