# EditText gets hidden when Keyboard appears

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, textinputlayout

So, I am using the following part of the code to get Input but as soon as the keyboard appears the text gets hidden under the Hint as in [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ22U.gif). How do I prevent this from happening.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">

        <EditText
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter message here..." />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: can you add you full layout code?

Comment: you are doing it wrong. It will be helpful if you post your whole xml file.

Comment: post your manifest code and which Activity above layout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android soft keyboard covers edittext field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest put it in the activity causing the problem

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add your layout in `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">

        <EditText
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter message here..." />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

and in `AndroidManifest.xml` add this code in your activity

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Answer (score 0):

set a height wrapcontent is causing the issue.
set height in linearlayout and use matchparent in autocompletetextview

remove layout_weight if not needed