# keyboard hidden in edit text fragment

Tags: android

*I have edit text in fragment when write in it,keyboard appear and hide in second and that is my xml code*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Company.Add_Fragment"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/liner1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/card1_company"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/image1_company"
                    />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/card2_company"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/card1_company"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/image2_company"/>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/liner1">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/boarder_rosheth"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:padding="18dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:background="#ffffff"
                            android:text="Medican Name"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/Specialization_company"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/boarder_rosheth"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:popupBackground="#7C89A8"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/city_company"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/boarder_rosheth"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:popupBackground="#7C89A8"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/boarder_rosheth"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:padding="18dp"
                            android:inputType="number"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                            android:background="#ffffff"
                            android:text="Phone Number"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/boarder_rosheth"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:padding="18dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                            android:background="#ffffff"
                            android:text="Mail"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/boarder_rosheth"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:padding="18dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                            android:background="#ffffff"
                            android:text="Company Name"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/back_share"
                        android:text="Share"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textColor="#0489F3"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:elevation="10dp"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: [Android soft keyboard covers EditText field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field)

There are a two steps to achieve your functionality

1. Wrap the layout inside a ScrollView
2. Inside the activity tag add

```
<activity
    android:name=".YOUR.ACTIVITY"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
/>
```

This was when your keyboard will open the layout will 'squeeze' itself upward and go back to normal on the keyboard being diselected