# Android: SoftKeyBoard cover up MultiLine edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a multi-line editText inside a scrollView follow by a button.

[image]

If using adjustPan, the softkeyboard cover up the whole editText, leaving only the first line.

[image]

When using adjustResize, even the button shows up which is worst

[image]

Here is my xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_save">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="600dp"
                android:background="@color/LightBlue"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter text"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minLines="8" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/gray_jll"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I want (temporarily achived using gravity bottom, but of course we want the text to display on the top using gravity top)

[image]

I looked at [Android soft keyboard covers EditText field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field).
But I am not using full screen mode.
`android:isScrollContainer="true"` does nothing.

Please tell me what is causing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: set `minHeight` attribute on the EditText. and set `gravity="bottom"`

Comment: But setting `minHeight` is not good at all. Because when you do that, it would produce a poor user experience for the user. The way Android handles it should be the best, i think.