# Keyboard Hides EditText When I try to type something

Tags: android

In the login page of my application, keyboard hides the EditText when I try to type something. I have tried putting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize` and also android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest.xml. It still hides the EditText. What shall I do to fix it. Please review my code.

**ActivityLoginNew.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    );
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_new);
    initViews();
    }
```

**activity_login_new.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
            style="@style/EditTextLogin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_lock"
            android:hint="Admin Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewVer"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineLeft" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/top_round"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/shaheen_logo_blue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            style="@style/h1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/value50_60_70"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/label_welcome"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineLeft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextEmpId"
            style="@style/EditTextLogin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_user"
            android:hint="@string/label_EmployeeId"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineLeft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            style="@style/EditTextLogin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/value30_40_50"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_lock"
            android:hint="@string/label_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineLeft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextEmpId" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textForgotPass"
            style="@style/p_bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/value20_25_30"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/label_forgotpassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineLeft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDeviceId"
            style="@style/p_bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/value20_25_30"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="756yt789753dbil"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineLeft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textForgotPass" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/value05_07_09"
            android:background="@drawable/login_btn"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/label_login"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineLeft"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textDeviceId" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textViewVer"
            style="@style/p_bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineLeft" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loadingBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/ProgressBarStyle"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loadingProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/ProgressBarStyle"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/value50_100_150" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/value50_100_150" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dubai_police_glow" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295672/android-soft-keyboard-covers-edittext-field) article (**including** the comments)? I'm sure you'll find the solution there, but since I don't know your Manifest in detail, I can't point you to the right answer.